# less-loader issue with webpack

Tags: less, webpack

I have an issue with loading flat-ui.less from the module. Need help.

I require flat-ui like this `require('flat-ui/less/flat-ui.less');` Also the versions for each related loader are `"less-loader": "^0.7.7",` `"css-loader": "^0.9.0",` `"style-loader": "^0.8.1",`

My `webpack.config.js` is like this:

```
    var path = require("path");
    var webpack = require("webpack");
    module.exports = {
      // This is the main file that should include all other JS files
      entry: "./public/scripts/main.jsx",
      target: "web",
      debug: true,
      devtool: "source-map",
      // We are watching in the gulp.watch, so tell webpack not to watch
      watch: true,
      watchDelay: 300,
      output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist", "assets"),
        publicPath: "/assets/",
        // If you want to generate a filename with a hash of the content (for cache-busting)
        // filename: "main-[hash].js",
        filename: "main.js",
        chunkFilename: "[chunkhash].js"
      },
      resolve: {
        // Tell webpack to look for required files in bower and node
        modulesDirectories: ['bower_components', 'node_modules', 'public'],
        fallback: ['./public']
      },
      module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
          { test: /\.less$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader!less-loader" },
          { test: /\.gif/, loader: "file-loader!url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=image/gif" },
          { test: /\.jpg/, loader: "file-loader!url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=image/jpg" },
          { test: /\.png/, loader: "file-loader!url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=image/png" },
          { test: /\.jsx/, loader: "jsx-loader" },

          // required for bootstrap/flat-ui
          { test: /\.woff$/,   loader: "url-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
          { test: /\.ttf$/,    loader: "file-loader" },
          { test: /\.eot$/,    loader: "file-loader" },
          { test: /\.svg$/,    loader: "file-loader" },
        ],
        noParse: /\.min\.js/
      },
      plugins: [
        // If you want to minify everything
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
      ]
    };
```

Unfortunately, I got this

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader!./~/flat-ui/less/flat-ui.less
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./fonts/lato/lato-black.eot in     /Users/Hao/Documents/project/node_modules/flat-ui/less
@ ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader!./~/flat-ui/less/flat-ui.less 2:66-104 2:118-156
```

Any idea of what's going on here??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure that your `@local-font-path: "../fonts/lato/";` in variables.less has been set to the right path and your font directory exits (you should have a /font and /css directory at the same level)

Comment: hmm, I `npm install flat-ui` and the patch is the same as you said. But still the issue

Comment: npm installs the `directory` in `node_modules` and your compiled css code is in `public/dist/css`, so you should copy the `font` directory to `public/dist/` too

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your application is looking for lato-black.eot in  /Users/Hao/Documents/project/node_modules/flat-ui/less, but it's not there. That's because it's being created somewhere else, I'm guessing /Users/Hao/Documents/project/public. In any case, find where it is being created, then add this to your webpack.config.js:

```
{ test: /\.eot$/,    loader: "file-loader&name=./path/to/file/[hash].[ext]" }
```

This will tell your application where to look for all eot files. You can do the same with all the other file types as well. Here's a link to the closed issue on the webpack github: https://github.com/webpack/file-loader/issues/32. Hope this helps.